# mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0

Tags: mysql, warnings, row, fetch

Code:

```
$qry_categorie = "SELECT id_category FROM wrs_category_product WHERE id_product = ". $row['id_product'] ."";
$query_categorie = mysql_query($qry_categorie);
$ciclaid = 0;
$lista_id_categorie_completa = '';

while($id_categorie = mysql_fetch_row($query_categorie)) {
    $lista_id_categorie_completa .= $id_categorie[$ciclaid] . ',';
    ++$ciclaid;
}
```

When I try:

```
echo $lista_id_categorie_completa;
```

I wish to have:

```
3,63,18,5,57
```

But echo prints:

```
3,,,,,,,
```

and with PHP error-reporting on, I see many errors about:

> mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0

Any ideas?

Comment: The code you posted does not call `mysql_result`. Please look at the line in the error message and post the relevant code.

Comment: i solved. i changed mysql_fetch_row with mysql_fetch_assoc and i initializated $id_categorie = array() before enter the while. Which of 2 real solved ? i'm too tired, i'll tell you tomorrow :) thanks